# Auto placing layout in React Native using binary packing

Tags: javascript, react-native, algorithm, sorting, gridview

I'm working on a React Native project where I want to implement a layout that has auto placing functionality while fitting all the children as tightly as possible. It just happens that CSS has a wonderful feature that allows grids to autoplace children, sadly React Native doesn't support CSS grid. I've seen a variety of React packages that seem to do this, but there's no implementation for React Native. Examples for React are:
[react-grid-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout), [Muuri](https://muuri.dev/), [bin-packing-grid](https://chris-l.github.io/bin-packing-grid/).
I have managed to get the items sorted using a binary packing algorithm, but the visualization is still an issue I can't seem to get working.

My question: is there a package for React Native that can do this or is there an algorithm for the visualization of a binary packed item array that works on React Native?

The grid should be able to auto place children as following. https://i.ibb.co/H72mXRG/Whats-App-Image-2022-07-09-at-2-05-23-AM.jpg

I also thought about using a grid that would work with coordinates (X and Y position), but I couldn't find a working example for React Native. This would also be a viable option.

Any clues in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found a package that does this. The name is [autoresponsive-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoresponsive-react-native).
[Docs](https://xudafeng.github.io/autoresponsive-react/), [Github](https://github.com/xudafeng/autoresponsive-react-native). Little outdated, but works perfectly. No Typescript support though.

Answer (score 1):

[This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoresponsive-react-native) (autoresponsive-react-native) supports platform independent handling for grids. Since the core functionality is independent from the visualization, it works on multiple platforms